# preventDefault() no me funciona como debería

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formularios, validación

Estoy haciendo un formulario, donde si falta completar alguno de los campos aparece bajo cada input el mensaje de advertencia correspondiente, y la idea es usar preventDefault() para que no se ejecute la función si falta completar cada campo. Al completar el formulario aparece un mensaje para confirmar o cancelar. El problema es que si pongo preventDefault() no se ejecuta nada o no funciona, depende en que funcion lo pruebe y ya probe meterlo en todos lados, si no lo pongo al clickear mas de una vez en el input submit se va duplicando el mensaje, solo se debe mostrar una vez, no le encuentro solución espero alguien me pueda ayudar, gracias! El código esta algo resumido porque muestra mucho mas cosas al hacer el click en el boton

HTML

## Hacé tu Reserva

```
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                  <!-- Name input -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresá tu nombre"/>
                    <span class="error" id="errorNombre" ></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                  <!-- Email input -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Ingresá tu email">
                    <span class="error" id="errorEmail" ></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  <!-- row -->
              
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                  <!-- Cancha input -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-select" id="tipoCancha">
                      <option value="0" selected>Seleccioná la cancha</option>
                      <option value="Tenis">Tenis</option>
                      <option value="Futbol 5">Fútbol 5</option>
                      <option value="Futbol 8">Fútbol 8</option>
                      <option value="Paddle">Paddle</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="error" id="errorCancha" ></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                  <!-- Dia input -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" min="2021-03-01" max="2021-04-10" id="diaIngresado">
                    <span class="error" id="errorDia" ></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                  <!-- Email input -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-select horario" id="horarioIngresado">
                      <option value="0" selected>Elegí el horario</option>
                      <option value="10">10:00</option>
                      <option value="11">11:00</option>
                      <option value="12">12:00</option>
                      <option value="13">13:00</option>
                      <option value="14">14:00</option>
                      <option value="15">15:00</option>
                      <option value="16">16:00</option>
                      <option value="17">17:00</option>
                      <option value="18">18:00</option>
                      <option value="19">19:00</option>
                      <option value="20">20:00</option>
                      <option value="21">21:00</option>
                      <option value="22">22:00</option>
                    </select>
                    <span class="error" id="errorHorario" ></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  <!-- row -->
              <div class="row">
                
              </div>  <!-- row -->

          </form>
          <div class="row">
            
       </div>
    </div>  <!-- row -->
 

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col">
         <div class="preciocancha" id="preciocancha"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="verReserva" value="Siguiente">
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>

    </div>
 </div>  <!-- row -->


 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">


          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
          <div class="loading" id="loading">
            <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="">
          </div>  
          </div>


          <div class="datosIngresados" id="datosIngresados" style="display: none;">
      
          
          <div class="titulo-reserva mb-3">
            
          </div>
            <div class="datos-reserva mb-5"></div> 
          
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container-boton">
                <div class="boton-reserva"></div>   
            </div>   
          </div> 
          <div class="col">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container-boton">    
                <div class="boton-reserva"></div>  
            </div>
          </div>
          </div> <!-- row --> 
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>  <!-- row -->

  </div>  <!-- container -->
    </div>
  
</section>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
let nombre
let email
let tipoCanchaIngresada 
let diaIngresado
let horarioIngresado
let precio 

// EVENTO Y FUNCION QUE ESTABLECE EL PRECIO SEGUN HORA Y CANCHA ELEGIDA

$("#horarioIngresado, #tipoCancha").change(function(){
  let horarioElegido = parseInt($("#horarioIngresado").val()) 
  let canchaElegida = $("#tipoCancha").val()

  //EL PRECIO ES DETERMINADO SEGUN EL TIPO DE CANCHA Y EL HORARIO

  if(horarioElegido >= 19 && horarioElegido <= 22 && canchaElegida == "Futbol 5" ){
    precio = 1800
  }else if (horarioElegido <= 18 && canchaElegida == "Futbol 5" ) {
    precio = 1500
  }if(horarioElegido >= 19 && horarioElegido <= 22 && canchaElegida == "Futbol 8" ){
    precio = 2200
  }else if (horarioElegido <= 18 && canchaElegida == "Futbol 8" ) {
    precio = 1800
  }if(horarioElegido >= 19 && horarioElegido <= 22 && canchaElegida == "Tenis" ){
    precio = 1400
  }else if (horarioElegido <= 18 && canchaElegida == "Tenis" ) {
    precio = 1100
  }if(horarioElegido >= 19 && horarioElegido <= 22 && canchaElegida == "Paddle" ){
    precio = 1200
  }else if (horarioElegido <= 18 && canchaElegida == "Paddle" ) {
    precio = 900
  } else {
    $("#errorHorario").hide()
  }
  
$("#preciocancha").text("Valor: $" + precio)


})



function validarNombre(){
  if ( nombre == "" ||  nombre.length <= 3 ){
   
    
    $("#errorNombre").text("ingresa tu nombre").show()
    $("#errorNombre").css("color", "#ec4553" )
  
  }
  else {
   $("#errorNombre").hide()
   let patternNombre = /^[a-zA-Z- ]*$/
   if(!patternNombre.test(nombre)){
     $("#errorNombre").text("Ingresa un nombre correcto").show()
   } else {
     $("#errorNombre").hide()
   }
   
  }

}


function validarEmail(){
  if (email == null || email == "" ){
   
    $("#errorEmail").text("Ingresa un correo electrónico").show()
    $("#errorEmail").css("color", "#ec4553" )
   
  }
  else {
    $("#errorEmail").hide()
    let patternEmail = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/
    if(!patternEmail.test(email)){
      $("#errorEmail").text("Ingresa un correo electrónico válido").show()
    }
    else {
      $("#errorEmail").hide()
    }
    
  }
}

function validarCancha(){
  let canchaElegida = $("#tipoCancha").val()
  if (canchaElegida == 0){
   
    $("#errorCancha").text("Debés seleccionar una cancha").show()
    $("#errorCancha").css("color", "#ec4553" )
  } else {
    $("#errorCancha").hide()

    
  }
}


function validarDia(){
  let diaIngresado = $("#diaIngresado").val()
  if(diaIngresado == 0) {

   $("#errorDia").text("Debés seleccionar el día").show()
    $("#errorDia").css("color", "#ec4553" )
  } else {
    $("#errorDia").hide()
 
  }

}


function validarHorario(){
  let horarioElegido = parseInt($("#horarioIngresado").val()) 
  if (horarioElegido == 0){
    
    $("#errorHorario").text("Debés seleccionar un horario").show()
    $("#errorHorario").css("color", "#ec4553" )
  } else {
    $("#errorHorario").hide()

    
  }

}


//FUNCION PARA VALIDAR TODOS LOS CAMPOS DEL FORM

function validarReserva() {
  validarNombre()
  validarEmail()
  validarCancha()
  validarDia()
  validarHorario()

}

$("#verReserva").click(function(e){
  
  e.preventDefault()
  $("#loading").css("display", "block")
 
  setTimeout(mostrarReserva, 1000)
  
})

function mostrarReserva (){
 
  $("#loading").css("display", "none")
  nombre = $.trim($("#nombre").val())
  email = $.trim($("#email").val())
  tipoCanchaIngresada = $("#tipoCancha").val()
  diaIngresado = $("#diaIngresado").val()
  horarioIngresado = $("#horarioIngresado").val()
  precio
 
 validarReserva()
 
$(".content-reserva").css("background-color", "#96bd42")

let tituloReserva = document.createElement("h3")
let textotituloReserva = document.createTextNode("Esta es tu reserva")
tituloReserva.appendChild(textotituloReserva)
let outputtext0 = document.getElementsByClassName ("titulo-reserva")[0]
outputtext0.appendChild(tituloReserva)


  let botonConfirmar = document.createElement("button")
  let textobotonConfirmar = document.createTextNode("Confirmar")
  botonConfirmar.appendChild(textobotonConfirmar)
  let outputtext2 = document.getElementsByClassName ("boton-reserva")[0]
  outputtext2.appendChild(botonConfirmar)
 

  let botonCancelar = document.createElement("button")
  let textobotonCancelar = document.createTextNode("Cancelar")
  botonCancelar.appendChild(textobotonCancelar)
  let outputtext3 = document.getElementsByClassName ("boton-reserva")[1]
  outputtext3.appendChild(botonCancelar)
  botonCancelar.addEventListener ("click", function() {
    $(".content-reserva, .titulo-reserva, .datos-reserva, .boton-reserva" ).empty()
    $("#datosIngresados").hide()

  })
 
 $("#datosIngresados").slideDown(500)

 
}



})
```

Comment: PreventDefault() sirve para que la página no se recarge, además en mostrar Reserva capturas los datos pero no haces nada con ellos

Comment: gracias por responder, entonces que deberia usar en lugar de preventDefault? en realidad en mostrar reserva hay mas codigo, al hacer click en el boton confirmar sale un alert, todo eso me funciona, pero no queria poner tanto codigo que no iba a tener sentido, solo quiero resolver como lograr que si no se llenan los campos el formulario no funcione, y una vez completado funcione

Comment: Bueno pon en un if la función validarReserva() y si es true todo está bien y si es false pues la función hara lo suyo pero seria bueno retornar un false